# What is the term used to describe a combined lexer and parser?

Tags: parsing, grammar, language-design, lexical-analysis, formal-languages

As far as I understand it: a lexer (lexical analyzer) converts a sequence of characters into a sequence of tokens, and a parser (syntax analyzer) *typically* converts a sequence of tokens into a parse tree.

Since these operations are often used in sequence, is there an unambiguous, single-word term to describe this? Or can parsing also refer to both lexical and syntax analysis?

Comment: "can parsing also refer to both lexical and syntax analysis?" Yes. [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/128888/233981) seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Both combined are still just "parsing". Extracting a lexer into a dedicated step is merely an optimisation (and I'd say a totally unnecessary one). When you talk about a parser without a dedicated lexer it will be a "lexerless" parsing - usually applied to approaches such as PEG and GLR.